# Messages app on MacBook Pro stopped sending messages to Android phones

Tags: macbook-pro, messages, android

Both my iMac and MacBook pro no longer let me send messages from the messages app. It worked like a charm before and now I'm not allowed to. There's no "message forwarding" option anymore in messages, so what in the heck do I do?

Help!

Comment: Your title states one problem, and the body describes two others.  Which one is actually the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding is absolutely still there.   On your iPhone, Settings > Messages > Text Message Forwarding.  Ensure this is enabled and your MacBook is included in the list of devices that can send and receive text messages.

Comment: The question is tagged with [tag:android], and the title also mentions Android phones though.